# Java object to URL params

Tags: java

I have Java POJO object and my goal is to convert it to URL parameters and use it in POST method.

```
...
public class PayseraRequest {

  private int projectid = 123;
  private int orderid = 987;
  private String accepturl = "http://www.test.com";
  ...
```

My goal is convert object `PayseraRequest` to String `urlParams`

> urlParams -> projectid=123&orderid=987&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com&...`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How convert object to urlParams string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write a method to do this, but you should URLEncode each parameter.  projectid and orderid do not need URLencoding but it doesn't hurt.  accepturl must definitely be UrlEncoded.  It is good practice to encode anything you want to put into the query string of a URL.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `toString` method of that class and with a say so StringBuilder get what you need.

Comment: I would recommend against this. Having a separate method to do this is a good idea, but `toString` has a speficic purpose. Maybe `toURLString`? (I did not downvote)

Answer (score 0):

You can check an example I have here:

https://github.com/lmpampaletakis/datumBoxSpringMVC/tree/master/datumBoxSpringMVC/src/main/java/com/lebab/datumbox

Your answer might be at SendRequest.java

You can replace the values of each parameter you want from your pojo